# Why Date.today is inserting previous date in Database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`Date.today` is showing correct date but when I used `Date.today` in `Model.create` statement it is inserting previous date in database Whereas `Date.today.to_datetime` is inserting correct date in database.

My question is why `Date.today` in `Model.create` method is inserting previous date in DB?

Comment: Precisely 24 hours before, or some other offset?

Comment: Are you putting `Date.today` into a timestamp column or a date column?

Comment: @mu is too short It is DATETIME column.

Comment: @Dave Newton, Not precisely 24 hours, But for Wed, 28 Nov 2012 it is inserting 2012-11-27 18:30:00.

Comment: Someone is filling in the time part of the timestamp with zeros and then there is a timezone adjustment somewhere. Don't put dates into timestamps, use `Time.now` instead of `Date.today` or switch the column to a date.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails there is a setup for a timezone in /config/application.rb :

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

For consistency all the times are stored in the database of Rails in UTC . So if you try on the console:

```
$ rake time:zones:local
```

you sold see all available time zones .

You can see the difference typing :

```
Time.now
```

and

```
Time.zone.now
```

I think default columns for time of creation and update , that Rails provides , should be OK for the most of cases.